Angular Animations - fade in / out works for DIVs, not fully for child components
In Angular 17,
My parent has this animation
Parent Component - animation configuration
 animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate('150ms', style({ opacity: 1 })),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('150ms', style({ opacity: 0 })),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],

View html element - fully works
When I apply it to the html in the template, this works fine:
   @if(showIcon) {

      <span class="material-symbols-outlined" [@fadeInOut]>
        check_circle
      </span>

    }

Child Component - half works (on fadeIn only)
When applied to a child component though, it only works on the fade in, and immediately cuts out, instead of fades out, when the boolean in the outer @if, switches back to false.
    @if(showChildComponent){
      <app-child-component
        [@fadeInOut]
        [someInput]="Input"
        (someEvent)="handleEvent($event)"/>
    }
  }

Is this a bug, or is my approach wrong?

Your code works fine, maybe you are missing to add something, please refer the below stackblitz, kindly replicate the issue and share back, if this answer does not work!
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import 'zone.js';
import { ChildComponent } from './app/child/child.component';
import { trigger, transition, style, animate } from '@angular/animations';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate('150ms', style({ opacity: 1 })),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [animate('150ms', style({ opacity: 0 }))]),
    ]),
  ],
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  template: `
    @if(showChildComponent){
      <app-child
        [@fadeInOut]/>
    }
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  showChildComponent = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.showChildComponent = !this.showChildComponent;
    }, 1500);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideAnimations()],
});

Stackblitz Demo

Doesn't work, when child is not simple text. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8oudxu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html

On second thoughts, if you add this to the css, :host {
display: block;
}... it does work!
